# How can SCOPE_IDENTITY return null when @@IDENTITY does not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

After executing an insert, I either select `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or `@@IDENTITY`.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns null but `@@IDENTITY` does not.

I don't understand how this is possible.

Can you think of a reason why this happens?

Comment: Can you provide more details... e.g. show the code where SCOPE_IDENTITY() is being called, and explain any other variables (e.g. is there a trigger involved?).

Answer (score 23):

here is one example of how SCOPE_IDENTITY() will be null but @@IDENTITY will have a value:

> insert into  a table with no identity,
>   that table has an insert trigger that
>   then inserts into a history table with
>   an identity.  SCOPE_IDENTITY() will be
>   null (no identity in the local scope),
>   but @@IDENTITY will report the
>   identity from the trigger.

FYI, there is a known bug with SCOPE_IDENTITY(): https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811

Your best bet with identities is to use OUTPUT INTO, it can capture a set of IDs and is not subject to the SCOPE_IDENTITY() bug:

```
declare @x table (tableID int identity not null primary key, datavalue varchar(10))
declare @y table (tableID int, datavalue varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @x values ('aaaa')
INSERT INTO @x values ('bbbb')
INSERT INTO @x values ('cccc')
INSERT INTO @x values ('dddd')
INSERT INTO @x values ('eeee')


INSERT INTO @x
    (datavalue)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.tableID, INSERTED.datavalue     --<<<<OUTPUT INTO SYNTAX
    INTO @y                                         --<<<<OUTPUT INTO SYNTAX
SELECT
    'value='+CONVERT(varchar(5),dt.NewValue)
    FROM (SELECT id as NewValue from sysobjects where id<20) dt
    ORDER BY dt.NewValue


select * from @x
select * from @y
```

Comment: While true, I don't think it was necessary to get into this much detail about an obscure bug that only manifests itself when you're inserting several rows and trying to retrieve a single identity.  `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` works without issue in 99% of cases.  Again, this is all correct but for someone who's still learning the difference between `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` it might be a bit overwhelming.

Comment: @Aaronaught, the OP doesn't supply the INSERT code, it could be an INSERT-SELECT that is using parallelism. Why I'd even wager that there is a 1% chance of this! ;-) At least in my answer I present two different ways that @@Identity and SCOPE_IDENTITY() can have different values, and not just the BOL definitions of them.

Comment: Just to clarify, as I had some difficulty understanding this myself, `@x` is the target table which data is going into and `@y` is the table created for the purpose of collecting the IDs of each new row inserted into `@x` in the final `INSERT` statement.  The data that comes from the `OUTPUT` statement goes into the `INTO` that follows it, not the one that precedes it.

Comment: @MattArnold, the data comes from the SELECT and is INSERTed into @x, the OUTPUT clause copies the inserted data in to @y

Comment: Thanks, that confirms how I thought it was behaving.

Answer (score 19):

KM hit the nail on the head:

- `@@IDENTITY` gives you the last IDENTITY value inserted - no matter where in which table it was inserted (think **triggers**, e.g. into audit tables! Or even a cascade of triggers.....)
- `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` gives you the last IDENTITY inserted in the scope of your statement, e.g. on the table(s) that your own, actual statement referenced (not those that might have been touched by a trigger)

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() fails to return proper results when parallelism is used: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811

Comment: how does this answer answer the question?  What's the solution as in keeping scope_identity IN scope?  that's the true 2nd problem to his issue.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` gives you the last `IDENTITY` from the current scope - there might be none, so you'd get `NULL`. If your insert on a table (without identity) however causes a trigger to fire which might be inserting e.g. auditing data into some other table (that does have an `IDENTITY` column), then `@@IDENTITY` will return that value (from the auditing table) to you. Does that make sense to you?? So please undo that downvote - it's totally not called for....

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. As far as I know the insert is the only statement in scope.  I will check to see if I have a trigger on this table.  (Would a trigger that inserted a table with no identity null the scope_identity? would is null @@identity as well?)

Comment: I solved my problem.  It seemed to be related to multiple connections open in my application.  I modified the app so all the updates used the same connection, and the problem went away.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns null after paramerized INSERT so @@IDENTITY fix my issue

Comment: Too bad Microsoft doesn't document this well that SCOPE_IDENTITY() could return NULL if your scope doesn't insert into a table with an IDENTITY column.

Answer (score 11):

SCOPE_IDENTITY will also return NULL when the insert is by sp_executesql as you are no longer in the scope of the INSERT!

Comment: +1. This happens when you insert through .NET's Entity Framework 6 `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT ...")`, it will wrap the command with sp_executesql, thus loosing the scope_identity.

Answer (score 3):

I found this on MSDN:

> The SCOPE_IDENTITY() function will return the null value if the function is invoked before any INSERT statements into an identity column occur in the scope.

You can read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Your SQL code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, both `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `OUTPUT INTO` didn't work because of `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger. The solution was to re-engineer the trigger to make it `AFTER INSERT` - luckily, I was able to do so in my case.