# sp_executesql Cross Server Insert return Scope_Identity()

Tags: scope, identity, sp-executesql

I have found answers to my question, they all state that the below syntax should work. It does not work for me. My output variable is always `NULL` so any help would be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000),
              @ParamDefinition nvarchar(500),
              @Id INT

SET @SqlCommand = N'INSERT INTO [server].db.dbo.table(Title) VALUES(''Insert Into table From othertable Test'')  SELECT @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
SET @ParamDefinition = N'@Id integer OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlCommand, @ParamDefinition, @Id OUTPUT

Select @Id
```

My `Select @Id` returns `NULL` every time, but the row is inserted into the table.

I found four or five results on Stack Overflow that state my code should work and should return the ID. But it does not.

I am working on a third party server, is there a chance that an error is being thrown that I am not seeing.

Thanks for any help.

Note: The statement below returns the value of the Scope_Identity(). Problem is I have no idea how to catch that value in a variable.

```
EXEC [Server].[db].[dbo].sp_executesql N'
     INSERT INTO [server].db.dbo.table(Title) VALUES(''Test Title Insert'')
     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
```

I have tried the syntax below with no luck

```
DECLARE @Id INT

EXEC @Id = [Server].[db].[dbo].sp_executesql N'
     INSERT INTO [server].db.dbo.table(Title) VALUES(''Test Title Insert'')
     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
```

Select @Id - @Id Is always NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter definition in the first snippet should use `int` rather than `integer`.

In addition, you could try using the OUTPUT keyword as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389354/how-can-scope-identity-return-null-when-identity-does-not).

Comment: I changed the parameters definition to int and the variable still returned NULL.

Comment: @Alwelder try using OUTPUT as in the linked question?